# Mockito spy on inputStream

Tags: java, mockito, inputstream

I am trying to make sure my function is calling the close() method on a given InptutStream:

```
@Test
public void testSpy() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = spy(new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello World".getBytes()));
    consumeAndClose(inputStream);
    verify(inputStream).close();
}

public void consumeAndClose(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    inputStream.readAllBytes();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

However, adding a spy to an InputStream seems to consume the stream already, because when it comes to readAllBytes() method I get the following error : *"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "original" is null"*

Using mockito-core version 4.8.1

Any idea on how to correctly use Mockito.spy on InputStream ?

Comment: Why not using mock instead of spy? If you are not testing the results anyway? Only the method invocation.

Comment: Yes, it would be a workaround. But I would have to mock also the behavior of readAllBytes(), or whatever ways the stream is consumed, which I don't want to have to do because I only want to test if the stream is closed at the end. No matter how the stream is consumed

Comment: If You are calling only this one method, it's not a problem to mock it. Your test should do one thing at a time, so one test could test it it reads properly, second if it closes the stream. Second test does not need to do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

As explained here : https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2589, there is a bug in mockito-core on jdk17.
I used **mockito-inline** instead of mockito-core and it worked just fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```